# Why is 1rem value different when inherited?

Tags: css, font-size

I have a container element with a `font-size` set to `1rem`
So the devtool tell me that the child element is 1rem too, right.
The value is 13.333px but my root element is 10px.

[image]

What am I missing ?

When I set the font-size on the child itself, 1rem is now 10px as expected, but why the inherited value doesn't work ?

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container">
  <p>this 1rem ?</p>
   <select>
     <option>this is not 1rem</option>
   </select>
  </div>
<form>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] to the question. I've tried a couple of things and can't get the "wrong" size to be applied.

Comment: Added a snippet to the initial post. Looks like it's a specific behaviour with select element.

Comment: Might be browser default styling.

Comment: Select elements are one of the least consistently implemented things in HTML, each browser applies their own styling. I believe Chrome effectively "blanks" the font-size, so you would need to manually apply a `font-size: inherit;` for it to act as you expect.

Comment: No choice then. thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select element doesn't inherit font size by default, you can add that rule yourself.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

select {
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <p>this 1rem ?</p>
    <select>
      <option>this is now 1rem</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<form>
```